# What's wrong with the definition of this struct?

Tags: c++, struct

I have defined the screen with a struct as below:

```
struct
{
    private:

    //data and attributes
    char character                  : 8;
    unsigned short int foreground   : 3;
    unsigned short int intensity    : 1;
    unsigned short int background   : 3;
    unsigned short int blink        : 1;

    public:

    unsigned short int row;
    unsigned short int col;

    //a function which gets row, column, data and attributes then sets that pixel of the screen in text mode view with the data given
    void setData (unsigned short int arg_row,
                  unsigned short int arg_col,
                  char arg_character,
                  unsigned short int arg_foreground,
                  unsigned short int arg_itensity,
                  unsigned short int arg_background,
                  unsigned short int arg_blink)
    {
        //a pointer which points to the first block of the screen in text mode view
        int far *SCREEN = (int far *) 0xB8000000;

        row = arg_row;
        col = arg_col;
        character = arg_character;
        foreground = arg_foreground;
        intensity = arg_itensity;
        background = arg_background;
        blink = arg_blink;

        *(SCREEN + row * 80 + col) = (blink *32768) + (background * 4096) + (intensity * 2048) + (foreground * 256) + character;
    }
} SCREEN;
```

but when I use characters with more than '128' ASCII code in using this struct, data will be crashed. I defined character field with 8 bit. so what's wrong with this definition?

Comment: ok. accepting my mistake. that's not important. what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Why are you using a bitfield on your `char`? I don't really understand that. I also cannot understand the meaning of "data will be crashed". What does that mean?

Comment: problem got solved. I had to use unsigned. I meant that the data will be wrong. that was coz of sign bit field.

Comment: I know what language I'm coding in. It was a typing mistake. I supposed when I said I accepted my mistake it was clear enough.

Comment: That was perfectly clear. But my last comment had moved on from C or C++. It asked two further questions.

Comment: there was no reason I used bitfield on my char.:) just to be in harmony with another valuables. :)

Comment: You should not do that then. Remove the bitfield on the char.

Comment: it doesn't make any problem. why so?

Comment: You don't use it on `row` and `col`. Why not? You use bitfields for bit packing. But `char` is addressable. So it's pointless. It will cause confusion. Carry on with it if you want. It's your call. I'd remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the c++ compiler you use apparently `char` is signed and so in an 8 bit character you fit values from `-128` to `127`(assuming two's complements representation for negative values is used). If you want to be guaranteed to be able to fit values greater than or equal to 128, use unsigned char.

Comment: iirc signednes of char is undefined(by standard, not by compilers)

Comment: `char` may be signed. Or may be unsigned.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not get what you mean by this comment. OP has declared the field as `char character                  : 8;` and this is a signed character and that is why it can not fit values of 128 and greater

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Why do you think that `char` is signed? The standard doesn't say that it must be.

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev Thats not true at all, in PowerPc CPU arch i.e. `char` is `unsigned char` and if you want to use `char` from `-128` to `127` you had to declare it as `signed char var`

Comment: @Zaibis apparently this is not the case with OP's system. I have changed my wording, now implying that an 8 bit character doesn't have to be signed but apparently is in this particular case.

Comment: You still should be able to store characters in the extended ASCII range in a signed char, you just have to encode them as negative numbers.